# Is Jesus the seed of Abraham?

Tags: virgin-mary

The Bible tells us that Jesus Christ was the seed of Abraham. Doesn't modern knowledge of reproduction tell us that the seed comes from the female and not the male? If this is so then Mary was from the seed of Sarah. Then Mary's seed was conceived by the Sprit of God thus a virgin birth. Could this be true?

Comment: Where in the Bible does it say that Jesus Christ was the seed of Abraham?

Comment: The OP is probably referring to Galatians 3:16.

Comment: This question is confusing. What 'modern knowledge of reproduction'? Do mean to say that being Jewish passes along the female line?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biology.

Answer (score 9):

"Seed" is sometimes used as a euphemism for sperm ([Ge 38:9](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/genesis/38-9.html)). It is frequently used in a metaphorical sense to mean "descendant."  ([Ge 3:15](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/genesis/3-15.html), [Ge 22:17](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/genesis/22-17.html)). In this sense, as it was applied to Jesus, it is less an assertion about biology, but instead has to do with family lineage and the fulfillment of God's promises to Abraham ([Ge 22:18](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/genesis/22-18.html)) and David ([2 Sa 7:12-16](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/2-samuel/passage.aspx?q=2-samuel+7:12-16)).

Answer (score 3):

In Galatians 3:16:

> Galatians 3:16  Now to Abraham and his seed were the promises made. He saith not, And to seeds, as of many; but as of one, And to thy seed, which is Christ.

The Greek word  Paul used is:                                                                                                                                                                           σπέρματι
which comes from

σπέρμα/    sperma

sper'-mah

From G4687; something sown, that is, seed (including the male “sperm”); by implication offspring; specifically a remnant (figuratively as if kept over for planting): - issue, seed.

From which we get our word Sperm; and this word was a derivative of the word

σπείρω

speirō /  spi'-ro

Probably strengthened from G4685 (through the idea of extending); to scatter, that is, sow (literally or figuratively): - sow (-er), receive seed.

This clearly shows that Paul's intent was to relate Jesus back to Abraham to whom the promise was made:

> Genesis 22:18  And in thy seed shall all the nations of the earth be blessed; because thou hast obeyed my voice.

The [Hebrew word for seed](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H2233&t=KJV) there is זרע (pronounced *zera'*).

Comment: @Frank Luke, Bruised reed and LCIII I'm confused why did you delete my depiction of the Greek when you used the Hebrew in your correction? also I am perplexed as to what the Hebrew word for seed has to do with the Greek since the New Testament was written in Greek and is not a translation from Hebrew.

Comment: Because זרע is Hebrew, not Greek. The Greek Paul uses in that verse is σπέρματι, which I put in the top, replacing the Hebrew *zera'*. Since you had quoted the Genesis source for Paul's quote, I put the Hebrew at the bottom so people could follow up on that route if they wanted.